# Does $X \sim Y$ and $P[D|X]=P[D|Y]$ imply $(D,X) \sim (D,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> Given random variables $D: \Omega \to \{-1,1\}$, $X: \Omega \to \{1,\dots, n\}$ and $Y: \Omega \to \{1,\dots, n\}$, such that
>
> $$X \sim Y$$
>
> and
>
> $$P[D| X] = P[D|Y]$$
>
> may one conclude that
>
> $$(D,X) \sim (D,Y)?$$

One may be tempted to use the definition of conditional probability and argue that

$$P[D=i, X=k ] = \int_{\{X=k\}}1_{\{D=i\}} dP = \int_{\{Y=k\}}1_{\{D=i\}} dP = P[D=i, Y=k ] ,$$

but since $P[X= k ] = P[Y= k ] $ does not necessarily imply that $\{X= k \} = \{Y=k \}$, I don't necessarily think this might be true...

Is it still possible to show that $(D,X) \sim (D,Y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P\left[D\mid X\right]=P\left[D\mid Y\right]$ tells us that: $$P\left[D=i,X=k\right]=P\left[D=i\mid X=k\right]P\left[X=k\right]=P\left[D=i\mid Y=k\right]P\left[X=k\right]$$

On base of $X\sim Y$ we can proceed with: $$\cdots=P\left[D=i\mid Y=k\right]P\left[Y=k\right]=P\left[D=i,Y=k\right]$$

Comment: Right! Of course I should have tried to use the more basic definition of conditional expectation for discrete valued random variables!